# A function for multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I want a function so that I can print the elements of a multidimensional array. The function maybe void or not. I tried creating such a function but I am unable to get the results.

Code:

```
void multi_deimensional_array_printing(int *(ref)[5], int size){

for (int *(ia)[5]{ref}; ia != ref + 5; ++ia) {// prob
    for (int rowsize{0}; rowsize != size; ++rowsize) {
        std::cout << rowsize << " ";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have the example code that you attempted?

Comment: minus 1 for link dumping.

Comment: minus vote retracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::cout << rowsize << " ";
```

you want to show what is in the array not where you are in the array.
So if you don't now how many i there is you can do:
    void multi_deimensional_array_printing(int **ref, int size){

```
  for (size_t i = 0; ref[i] != NULL ; ++i) {
    for (size_t a = 0; a < size; ++a) {
      std::cout << ref[i][a] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

and in your case:

```
void multi_deimensional_array_printing(int *(ref)[5], int size){

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5 ; ++i) {
    for (size_t a = 0; a < size; ++a) {
      std::cout << ref[i][a] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can receive an array by reference and deduce the extents using template argument deduction:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b166164ac4d9c9a)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
void print(T (&arr)[N][M]) {
    for (size_t i = 0ul; i<N; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0ul; j<M; ++j)
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[][3] = {
        { 1,2,3 },
        { 4,5,6 },
    };

    print(a);
}
```

Prints

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```